# Vanity countertop support for piece over toilet

Tags: bathroom, countertops, vanity, granite, quartz

I was looking at some photos from model homes and like the vanity countertop cut:

[image]

How do they support the stone where it goes out to the top of the toilet tank?

I don't see anything below the stone to support it in that area.

Would it be OK like that where it is "floating"?

[image]

Comment: FYI, put some consideration into making sure the tank is still accessible for repair purposes if you go this route. Aesthetics are nice, but I've seen some installations where access to the tank basically requires removing the countertop.

Comment: @user3757614 worst case scenario the tank could be removed from the bowl no reason to remove a countertop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most natural stone won't cantilever that far without breaking. Even a synthetic like corian may or may not work.

There's probably a narrow ledger (~1x2) supporting the back.

Comment: Absolutellllllllllly..... Here is a quick google search result where you can see what is described in the answer: https://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/custom-vanities-with-shelf-over-toilet.jpg

Comment: Would some L shape metal piece work? Also what would be the maximum overhang outside of the supporting ledger?

Comment: L shaped metal would absolutely work. Overhang-wise, 8" is probably safe, but it depends on the counter material.

Comment: If it's a well planned job, they could've just finished the wall after the counter, completely hiding the support.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to support it just in case. Countertop support brackets will definitely help in this matter. Sizes range from 8x6 all the way to 24x16. Just keep in mind to leave enough space for future toilet repairs if you are going to install right above it.